# C# Opengl game cs 1.6 screenshot (Opentk Library error)

Tags: c#, opengl, screenshot

I put this question on opengl forum's:

http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/181549-OpenGL-screenShot-a-game

&

www. opentk. com/node/3312

One person said to me i'm nothing taking a screenshot of a game, and i'm after this have created a dll and injected on the game (counter strike 1.6).

but i get some errors when execute framebuffer and grabscreenshot!

this is a print off error:

[image]

i'm are injecting with this source:

```
void Inject()
    {
        System.IntPtr TargetProcessHandle;
        int TargetBufferSize;
        String pszLibFileRemote;
        int pfnStartAddr;
        Process[] TargetProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("hl");
        TargetProcessHandle = OpenProcess(0x1F0FFF, false, TargetProcess[0].Id);
        pszLibFileRemote = Application.StartupPath + ("\\dll.dll");
        pfnStartAddr = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("Kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
        TargetBufferSize = 1 + pszLibFileRemote.Length;
        int Rtn;
        int LoadLibParamAdr;
        LoadLibParamAdr = VirtualAllocEx(TargetProcessHandle, 0, TargetBufferSize, 4096, 4);
        Rtn = WriteProcessMemory(TargetProcessHandle, LoadLibParamAdr, pszLibFileRemote, TargetBufferSize, 0);
        CreateRemoteThread(TargetProcessHandle, 0, 0, pfnStartAddr, LoadLibParamAdr, 0, 0);
        CloseHandle(TargetProcessHandle);
    }
```

I have edit some code on dll to:

```
Bitmap snapShotBmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = snapShotBmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                                                  System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        GL.ReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgr, PixelType.UnsignedByte,
                      bmpData.Scan0);
        snapShotBmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        return snapShotBmp;
```

I'm programing with c# language!

Comment: without knowing spanish i presume that an object is null

Comment: how i can put put something in ? because in a form they give me black screenshot but in dll when i inject on CS 1.6 give me that error!

Comment: see my edit on dll code!